# How to see logs from npm installation?

Tags: npm-install

I am unable to install ionic through npm. Are there any logs that I can check to see what's wrong and if yes, where are they located?

What I see is the waiting stick dancing forever. I've waited for an hour or so but nothing changes.

Answer (score 376, accepted):

**Append the `--loglevel verbose` argument to the command you want to run** and all logs will be shown on STDERR and saved to `npm-debug.log` file in the current working directory.

Example usage: `npm install ionic --loglevel verbose`.

Running the `npm` commands like this, shows the logs in realtime and saves the logs to the directory its running within.

---

For permanent solution, just edit the global `npm` configuration. To do this, run `npm config edit` command and add `loglevel=verbose`. Now every `npm` command will show detailed logs

Comment: It's not particularly clear, but some options are documented [here](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/config). Or alternatively, run `npm help 7 config`.

Comment: Update config via command
`npm config set loglevel verbose`

Comment: That is not a lot of additional logging. Is there anything that can help debug networking problems?

Comment: `-d`, `-dd` and `-ddd` give increasing amounts of output. In my current case only `-ddd` was somewhat helpful, but not even that very much.

Comment: @FabianRöling , `-d` == `--loglevel info` , `-dd` == `--loglevel verbose` , `-ddd` == `--loglevel silly` . See: [Shorthands and Other CLI Niceties § config | npm Docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/using-npm/config#shorthands-and-other-cli-niceties)

Comment: this doesn't seem to work if the command doesn't actually error out.

Comment: for me `npm -ddd i` actually works out like a charm. Keep an eye on the order, before the log verbose and then the command install.

Comment: For some reason, this does not work to print output from install scripts. Some module has `const log = require('npmlog'); log.info('install', 'Something ... ')`  but npm install command does not print out any of it unless an error happens - then suddenly those info messages get printed. How do I force it to print everything from the module install scripts?

Comment: Hello
I want to know what the verbose flag alone means
For example, I want to install npm with the --verbose , what does this mean?
npm i --verbose