# Terminal hang when try to install Vue CLI onto mac

Tags: node.js, vue.js, npm

[image: screenshot of terminal]

I am trying to install Vue Cli onto my macbook, but the terminal hangs everytime no matter what command I use.

You can see that I tried to uninstall vue cli and start again using the command `npm uninstall vue-cli -g`

Then I checked that both npm and nodejs are installed onto my laptop using `npm -v`and `node -v`

Then I tried to install vue again using the command `npm install -g @vue/cli`

it just shows `⸨░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░⸩ ⠧ rollbackFailedOptional: verb npm-session 1563616353d810b`and hangs

It will hang for a few hours until I terminate it. I am not sure if this could be due to an Internet connection problem, although my connection at home is quite fine. I read other relevant posts as well but all the other problems are different from mine. They all at least got an error from the terminal. I am really stuck.

Thank you in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: Sometimes installing a package globally (`-g` flag) requires `sudo`, but this depends on how `npm` is installed on your system.

Comment: Try installing again with [verbose logging enabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39412424/how-to-see-logs-from-npm-installation) then check `npm-debug.log` to see where it failed.