# Where can I find firebase cloud function deploy logs? Path starts with /www-data-home/.npm/_logs/

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I am getting an error message

```
Build failed: npm ERR! Cannot read property 'firebase-admin' of undefined\n\nnpm ERR! 
A complete log of this run can be found in:\nnpm ERR!
/www-data-home/.npm/_logs/2022-11-23T04_36_44_234Z-debug.log; Error ID: beaf8772"
```

Where is this www-data-home location?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was having the same error, updated package.json to use engine: 16, deployed again and then it worked (believe it forced updating all npm that could have been corrupted remotely).

Comment: yeah, I had to delete the function, update to the latest and redeploy. painful

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in this documentation on [Viewing logs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/writing-and-viewing-logs#viewing_logs)

> Logs for Cloud Functions are viewable either in the Google Cloud
> Console, Cloud Logging UI, or via the firebase command-line tool.
>
> Using the Firebase CLI To view logs with the firebase tool, use the
> functions:log command:   `firebase functions:log`
>
> To view logs for a specific function, provide the function name as an
> argument:
>
> `firebase functions:log --only <FUNCTION_NAME>`   For the full range
> of log viewing options, view the help for functions:log:
>
> `firebase help functions:log`
>
> You can view logs for Cloud Functions in the Cloud Logging UI using
> filter as those resource types
>
> `resource.type="cloud_function"`

Refer this [npm docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/using-npm/logging#setting-log-file-location)  on npm logging.

> The npm CLI has various mechanisms for showing different levels of
> information back to end-users for certain commands, configurations &
> environments.
>
> All logs are written to a debug log, with the path to that file
> printed if the execution of a command fails.You can find the
> `npm-debug.log` file in your `.npm` directory. To find your `.npm`
> directory, use `npm config get cache`.

You can also check this stackoverflow [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39413248/18265638)