# package.json github ssh prompts for credentials for npm ci

Tags: git, authentication, github, ssh, prompt

I have the below private git repo mentioned in the package.json variable:

`git+ssh://git@github.com:knowyrtech/actions_param.git`

I setup ssh keys on my Windows and I m able to authenticate and clone the repositories as below without any prompt / user-input:

Works -> `git clone git@github.com:knowyrtech/actions_param.git`

However, the below does not work and prompts for credentials which is the problem i wish to seek a solution for:

`git+ssh://git@github.com:knowyrtech/actions_param.git`

`npm ci`

It runs and then prompts asks me for authentication.

Can you please suggest?

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure your private key is not encrypted, or you will have to deal with "[adding your SSH key to the ssh-agent](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent?platform=windows#adding-your-ssh-key-to-the-ssh-agent)".
For testing, a regular private key is easier.

Second, in your CMD session (where you try your npm command), for the key with

```
set "GIT_SSH_COMMAND=ssh -i %USERPROFILE%\.ssh\mykey"
```

Even if your key is the default one (`id_rsa` for instance), that is one more signal for Git (through `npm`) to use it.

Then retry the `npm ci` command, maybe [with a verbose mode](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39413248/6309), to ensure it actually is your private repository which is the issue (and not some other dependency).